# How convert an annotation (all its diff properties) into a JSON object using Jackson/ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, objectmapper

I have an annotation and during its runtime use on a method, I want to convert it 9and all its property values) into a JSON object.

The annotation:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String name();
    Integer age();
}
```

Use of it:

```
public class MyClass {
    @MyAnnotation(name = "test", age = 21)
    public String getInfo()
    { ...elided... }
}
```

When using reflection on an object of type `MyClass` and getting the annotation from its `getInfo` method, I would like to be able to convert the annotation to JSON. But it doesn't have any fields (since @interfaces can't have fields), so is there a way to configure an `ObjectMapper` to use the methods as properties instead?

```
//This just prints {}
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

Use `@JsonGetter` and pass it the name of the field you want it to represent.

Example:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    @JsonGetter(value = "name")
    String name();

    @JsonGetter(value = "age")
    Integer age();
}
```

This will output as the json: `{"name":"test","age":21}`